# Difference between WhatsApp audio and WhatsApp voice notes

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

- What is the difference between WhatsApp audio and WhatsApp voice notes?
- If I record a voice conversation, where is it going to be stored? Is it in WhatsApp audio folder or in WhatsApp voice notes?
- In which folder  all of my received voice notes get saved?

Answer (score 3):

The folder `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/` contains the downloaded audio files that you received as an attachement from a contact. The file names usually start with `AUD-`.

The folder `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes/` contains the voice files that you recorded using your Whatsapp. They usually start with filenames containing `PTT-` and stored under corresponding folders with date of the recording.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23112542/?category=5245251) Document

***Choose Audio to*** record a message or send an existing audio from your phone.

**But**

**WhatsApp voice notes** - To send a voice message.

**Folder** `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Voice Notes/`

**Folder** `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Audio/`